# Need to Split the output in Row & Column

Tags: shell, shell-script, columns

I am currently working on one script which will capture all the Endpoint Name & Ongoing calls on my switch and will send the output to one file.

Output is currently coming like below.

```
Registration ID                               Nitin_01
Ongoing Calls                                 9 (0:9)
Registration ID                               Nitin_02
Ongoing Calls                                 6 (6:0)
```

more endpoint coming below like above (there is around 200+ endpoint)

What I want here that output should come like below.

```
Registration ID  Ongoing Calls
Nitin_01           9
Nitin_02           6
```

Script is as below. After the suggestion when i saved the below output in script then it is giving me the output like i wanted to see, however it still not coming in raw & column.

Output is coming like as below.

```
Nitin SBC:~ # cat /root/Nick.csv | more
Registration ID Ongoing Calls
  Nitin_03 26
  Nitin_01 0
```

Code:

```
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
ifile=/root/Nick.csv
{ date '+%F %T'; 
  "$ipath"/cli iedge list |
     awk 'BEGIN { print "Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"}
        /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
        /Ongoing Calls/ { print id, $3 }'
} >> "$ifile"`
```

`cli iedge list` is the command which help us fetch the information of all the Endpoint is configured on the switch.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Hi Sir..I added "----" because i just wanted to elaborate the output i want to see.

Comment: Pretty please, read the [formatting section](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), especially the [code](http://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) section that allows you to either put code that will show up with coloring or allow you to show the output as it is (multiple spaces won't be eaten by web browsers, ...).

Comment: I helped edit the code. But I'm unsure the output is formatted the way you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
ifile=/root/Nick.csv
{ date '+%F %T'; 
  "$ipath"/cli iedge list |
    awk -v OFS='\t' \
      'BEGIN { print "Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"}
       /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
       /Ongoing Calls/ { print id, $3 }'
} >> "$ifile"
```

Comment: - He sir, i just edited the code, but it not showing me anything after.

**NitinSBC:~ # ./sample.sh**
'Registration ID Ongoing Calls  <=== No output after that'


MEM=`"$IPATH"/cli iedge list | egrep "Registration ID|Ongoing Calls" | cut -f6`;
awk 'BEGIN { print "Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls"}
      /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
      /Ongoing Calls/ { print id, $3 }'
echo `date "+%F %T"`",$MEM,$awk" >> $IFILE;'

Comment: Sorry for confusion. My question is still same i pasted above in question.

Comment: I am extremely sorry.. i just pasted the exact code i have in file

Comment: okay sir..i pasted in question only

Comment: Okay sir..Sorry again..i just updated the question.. Thanks a lot for your help.. I can see moreover the way i wanted to see.. but still columns and raw is not coming

Comment: @NitinKapoor Look back at your question - I think you screwed up the formatting.

Comment: @NitinKapoor I added tabs to the output. Is that what you meant by rows and columns?

Comment: @NitinKapoor you can replace the `print id, $3` part with `printf("%15s %s",id,$3)` if you want strict formatting.

Comment: @jw013 Well, my `C` background is showing... xD You are indeed right in that it works without parentheses, but let me be the devil's advocate here and point out that it also seems to work with them (on GNU Awk 3.1.8 at least).

Comment: @user43791 You are right. I discovered the same and deleted my prior erroneous comment but it turns out you saw it anyways. After reviewing the [`awk` grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_16), I learned that the print statements do accept parentheses after all so carry on as you were.

Comment: @user43791 thanks .. when i tried `printf("%15s %s",id,$3)` it is not giving me in raw and column, it is just mixed the output. I can attached the output in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use `grep`, then you could do something like this:

```
paste <(cat input.txt | grep -oP "Registration ID\s+\K.+") <(cat input.txt | grep -oP "Ongoing Calls\s+\K.+")
```

This is assuming that you saved the output of `cli iedge list` in some `input.txt` file.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. cli iedge list is the command which is running first and not sending data to any file, it is just running on script and from there we are putting the filter for registration ID and ongoing calls and those filtered data i am sending in vport.csv as i mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your awk script to output tabs and pipe through `column -t -s<TAB>`

```
ipath=/usr/local/nextone/bin
ifile=/root/Nick.csv
{ date '+%F %T'; 
  "$ipath"/cli iedge list |
     awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"; print "Registration ID", "Ongoing Calls" }
        /Registration ID/ { id = $3; next }
        /Ongoing Calls/ { print id, $3 }' |
     column -t -s$'\t'
}  >> "$ifile"`
```

Output will be:

```
2015-06-03 11:11:33
Registration ID      Ongoing Calls
Nitin_01             9
Nitin_02             6
```